# Shunya (nothingness) vs Purna (fullness) -- How to reconcile the seemingly contradictive statements in Uttara Gita?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, buddhism

In the Uttara Gita Chapter 1, Sloka 35 describes the Atma as

> ऊर्ध्वशून्यमधःशून्यं मध्यशून्यं यदात्मकम् ।
>   सर्वशून्यं स आत्मेति समाधिस्थस्य लक्षणम् ॥
>
> When (one perceives) the Atma is perceived as Nothing Upwards, Nothing down, Nothing in between and nothing everywhere, he is established in Samadhi with the Atma.

Now, the Uttara Gita sloka 37 (and 38) describes the Atma as

> ऊर्ध्वपूर्णमधःपूर्णं मध्यपूर्णं यदात्मकम् ॥ सर्वपूर्णं स आत्मेति समाधिस्थस्य लक्षणम् ।
>
> When (one perceives) the Atma is perceived as complete (full) Upwards, complete (full) down, complete (full) in between and complete (full), everywhere, he is established in Samadhi with the Atma.

**Do these slokas (in the context established in the text) contradict each other?**

Also, is this the Shunya Vada of Buddhism. If yes, then is Uttara Gita an interpolated text or is Shunya Vada recognized by Vedanta?

Comment: Very good Qn. Strongly related: [What is Fullness and Emptyness (void) according to the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23474/1049)

Comment: @iammilind - Thank you. Just read through the link. I have not heard of Shunyavada in Hindu texts till now. This mention in Uttara Gita whose source cannot be accurately traced is somewhat puzzling.

Comment: they are not contradictory. also shunya vada of buddhism is wrongly interpreted by many. you may want to read the following link. he explains the difference very well - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: This is the very use of Oxymoron or Paradox which is often used in our Scriptures to describe the incomprehensible nature of God. Like, we say "Devi is formless beyond any conception" then again we say "Devi has three eyes, four hands, and is red in appearance". You can find many such contradictory sentences to show that God is beyond understanding.

Comment: One of the most famous such quote we find in Scriptures is thus- **यस्यामतं तस्य मतं मतं यस्य न वेद सः, अविज्ञातं विजानतां विज्ञातमविजानताम्‌** **"He who does not think about Brahma is actually thinks about Brahma, and he who thinks about Brahma does not think about Brahma. Brahma is unknown to those who know Brahma, and Brahma is known to those who do not know Brahma"** This is a poetic device to show a thing contradictory to show that it is beyond comprehension. Kena Upanishat

Comment: Amazing, thank you @AnuragSingh! The Uttara Gita however mentions voidness as the truth and fullness as something that's unreal but prescribed for those who cannot conceive voidness. This is clear from Arjuna's question on Uttara Gita 1. 39.Thats where this seems to be even more puzzling.

Comment: The verses are meant to simply imply the infinitude and incomprehensibility of Brahman to the mind. What we think of as spatial infinitude or spatial fullness does not apply to Brahman as Brahman is Pure Consciousness and is dimensionless - spatial dimensions only apply to the material sensual universe. The Spirit has no dimensions. When thinking of the word infinite in regard to Brahman, think of It as that which 'touches everything' rather than infinite dimensional space. When thinking of fullness think - where is Brahman not?

Comment: Voidness is void of physical matter. Upwards and downwards, etc., are spatial dimensions not spirit.The verses are trying to convey an idea, don't try to interpret them literally. Metaphors work one way, not two. If I say a man is like a tiger, you know that I don't mean he's physically a tiger. Likewise, I don't mean that a tiger is the same as a man.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: Thank you. That brings a nice perspective to understand the text.